# Can I sort a bunch of values without retaining the actual content of the string? Two-Key sort one from on-premise another in the cloud

Tags: sorting, math

### What do I want to do

I want to sort a bunch of strings, simple enough.

### What are my constraints

I have the original text stored on-premises which has the real text which I want to sort, the cloud has some other "columns" of data which is not on-premises and for security reasons I cannot take the original text from on-premises to the cloud.
The real constraint is that I cannot have all the data in one place which causes sorting, paging on values across on-premises & cloud data difficult.

### What I thought of (and where I need help)

Maybe I can take a hash or some other way of extracting certain data from the string in such a way that the original string cannot be reproduced (takes care of the security thing) but the extracted string would be enough that I can do sorting on it.

### Example

on-premises data:

`[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abcd"
  }
]`

cloud data:

`[
   {
     "id": 1,
     "price": "20"
   }
]`

I need to sort on both price and name in the above example (imagine a 100,000 rows of such data).

Comment: How do you determine the value of the other columns for any of the strings? Do you send the string to the cloud and get them? Do you send some kind of key or index and thereby index the cloud values?

Comment: we sync ids to the cloud so that we can relate data on-premises to the one in cloud

Comment: I doubt that in general case there is a transformation of strings that is non-reversible but preserves sorting order. After all what would stop you from doing the same transformation on a test string and then comparing it to the given one (target)? And if you can do this, you can find the target pretty fast using binary search.

Comment: If you locally have IDs to match local strings to the cloud, why don't you just sort strings locally and then use the sorted list of IDs to sort data in the cloud? What is the reason to try to go through all this mess with "hashing"?

Comment: there are a few data points in the cloud which cant go on-premise and sorting can happen on those fields as well, as of today we only do the sorting on local ones, however, doing the combination becomes an issue, hence I wanted one place where there is enough data to do the sorting

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to store pairs of a string and the corresponding id, e.g. in two lists/arrays (whatever the programming language of your choice offers).
Then start sorting the strings, but each time you move a string, move the id the same way.

Alternatively, most programming languages offer constructs which allow to make pairs and then you sort those pairs according to strings, which will automatically move the ids around.

Both ways mean that after sorting, you can still find the id for each string, then with that id you can access the corresponding cloud data as usual.

As an example, the programming language C offers the compound data type construct

```
struct IdStringPair
{
    int id;
    char* string;
    /* actually just the address of where the full string is stored,
       but basically what you probably want to use */
};
```

Hardly any programming language exists which does not offer something similar.

If conversely the data to sort by is in the cloud, then sorting has to take place in the cloud, i.e. by something being able to execute the sorting algorithm. Make sure that you sort the id along with the key. Then finding the non-cloud string is again the same as before. Whatever you previously did to find a string to an id, do it with the id you got from the cloud sorted data.
This is the same as the first situation/solution, just mirrored.

The core concept is to always sort the ids along with the key (and other data) and thereby dispose of the need to have the data from the other side of the gap between clould and premise. That is applicable to all versions of the sorting of separated data.

Comment: "there are a few data points in the cloud which cant go on-premise and sorting can happen on those fields as well, as of today we only do the sorting on local ones, however, doing the combination becomes an issue, hence I wanted one place where there is enough data to do the sorting" I think you misunderstood the problem statement, or maybe I have misunderstood your solution.

Comment: Do you have some programming language at your disposal for creating something of a simulation of your problem? The concept of a [mcve] is probably not 100% applicable. But could you use the formal expressions of any programming language to give a new angle on this? Otherwise please at least make some examples of strings and cloud-data sets. Not anything real of course, be anonymous (names of comic heros for example) and maybe even change values (from critical stuff like cholesterol levels to length of hair...) Show some sortings you would like to do if you had all data in one place.

Comment: I see, but it is exactly as I expected. Please provide more examples of data and at least two examples of desired sorting (one premise, one cloud). Choose the data and the sorting examples to demonstrate your problem. Why can't you sort premise by name and access price via id? Or why can't you sort cloud by price and access name via id?

Comment: sometimes the sort needs to happen first by price and then by name which leaves me the choice of how much data I can bring in from the cloud into memory and then sort it as not all of that data will actually be used due to pagination

Comment: Do I understand correctly. You could sort by price in the cloud and then get the price-sorted list of ids to the premise, but you could not get the prices to the premise. But then you want to sort everything which has the same price by name as second key? In that case I need to extend my answer a little, but I already have an idea how. Please confirm that I understand the problem correctly. If possible make an example with a few data-sets of same price, so that the need to sort by second key can be demonstrated and I have something I can refer to in my explanation.

Comment: I think you could rephrase the question a little, or simply add the information from the comment to the question itself. That would make the now really interesting problem clearer, i.e. I think it makes for a more interesting question, which in turn might attract upvotes, if you are interested in that. The core of what is missing (or what I fail to read in your question) is the two-key-sorting, with one key only available in cloud and one key only on premises.

Comment: edited the question title, yes, essentially I cant take the name to the cloud, I can bring the price to on-premises, however getting the full list down from the cloud across the board, combining in the memory and then sorting is disastrous for performance which is the problem, not that I am saying you are suggesting the latter, just wanted to make stuff clearer.